# How to access simple web service with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this 'web service' I made that when accessed:

```
"http://192.168.0.1/api/v1/search/?query=thequery"
```

returns a JSON string as the result. Its very simple it just return string.

I am trying to access it from my client site using JQuery:

```
function doSearch() {
    $.ajax({    
        url: "http://192.168.0.1/api/v1/search/?query=" + $('#searchfield').val(),
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json_results){
            alert('Alert title', 'Alert message!');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error', 'Alert message!');
        }
    });
}
```

Although I when the web service return properly when accessed with curl or the web browser, when accessed through $.ajax it always fail, showing the Error alert message box.

**EDIT:** From Firebug console I get:

```
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length  131
Connection  keep-alive
```

However, the reponse is empty.

Comment: So, what's the error information? Why are you trying to access it with jsonp if it's not a jsonp service?

Comment: This is a support/bug/chatroom question, not a SO question.

Comment: @Dave Newton I just put that error: function(), how do I get the error info you are saying?

Comment: That information is in the [jquery .ajax() function docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

You don't have a JSONP service; you're just returning JSON.

So, use the proper `datatype`:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Comment: Thanks, however still 'error: function()' is the function that is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery.getJSON can be used for that purpose.

Comment: Can you give me an example to use getJSON for this instance?

Comment: For instance; $.getJSON("http://192.168.0.1/api/v1/search/", { query: "blah"}, function(data){ ... });

Comment: I wonder why when I tried this approach the callback function is not called? I just placed a 'alert(data);' to see if the callback will be invoked.

Comment: I tried Firbug and see that the parameter is there, i.e. the query. The response from the GET is empty.

Comment: The $('#submit').click function which fires dOSearch is attached to a anchor, could this be the problem?